# react-to-print prints different layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-to-print

I want to print in reactjs a Know Your Customer Form on button press after filling customer details.
So to do this I made two Forms; First one is the normal one filled through the client to fill customer data and the second form takes the data and inputs in a read only form.
The problem is when I use use react-to-print the rendered layout is different from window.print and  I don't know why!
This is my function

```
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });
```

And this is the button

```
            <button
              className="btn btn-light"
              variant="secondary"
              style={{ width: "10%" }}
              type="button"
              onClick={() => {
                handlePrint();
              }}
              disabled={props.loading}
            >
              print
            </button>
```

and this is the printable form

```
        <NonShowDiv>
        <PrintableKYCForm ref={componentRef} onClick={handlePrint} makeToast={props.makeToast} />
        </NonShowDiv>
```

and this is the css for NonShowDiv

```
export const NonShowDiv = styled.div`
  display: none;
  @media print {
    display: block;
  }
`;
```

This css is used to only show the form for printing.

This is the wrong output using react-to-print)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMqYq.png)

This is how it should look like!(using window.print())[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfMeT.png)

Comment: It sounds like you have a style being applied to a parent node of the content `react-to-print` is printing. As noted in the [README](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print?tab=readme-ov-file#common-pitfalls), `react-to-print` only sees global styles, and styles applied to the selected content and down. It cannot pick up on styles applied to parent nodes of the content.